# Golang cannot display retrieved data in view

Tags: go

Hopefully this is my last question to do with pointers ever:

I am calling a repository method to get a slice of gym classes. I am displaying them in a view like this:

```
    {{ range .}}
            {{.VideoPath}} << Correct
            <br>
            {{.Instructor.Email}} << Blank
            <br>
            {{.ClassType.ClassTypeCode}} << Blank               
    {{end}}
```

The instructor and classtype fields are coming up as empty structs, but in the ClassRepository I did some Printlns and the correct data gets printed. Somewhere there is a pointer issue or something. What have I done wrong?

Here is the repository:

```
package repositories    

type ClassRepository struct {
    Gorp gorp.SqlExecutor
}

func (c ClassRepository) ClassesForLastNDays(days int) []entities.Class {
    var classes []entities.Class
    // Gets the classes - omitted for brevity
    c.populateClassRelationships(classes)
    return classes
}

func (c ClassRepository) populateClassRelationships(classes []entities.Class) {
    for i := range classes {
        class := classes[i]

        // ClassType
        obj, err := c.Gorp.Get(entities.ClassType{}, class.ClassTypeCode)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        class.ClassType = *obj.(*entities.ClassType)
        fmt.Println(class.ClassType) << Returns correct data

        // Instructor and Equipment
        Same for instructor and Equipment


    }
```

### }

UPDATE:

After a whole lot of printlns I can confirm that the issue is here after populateClassRelationships the populated values are all lost.

```
func (c ClassRepository) ClassesForLastNDays(days int) []entities.Class {
        var classes []entities.Class
        // Gets the classes - omitted for brevity
        c.populateClassRelationships(classes) <<<< In the method,Println has values
        return classes <<<< Values have been lost
    }
```

Comment: Can you reduce this? This is a bit unwieldy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your function `populateClassRelationships` where it is not modifying the original data structure as illustrated by the following code which finally outputs:

```
[1]
[]
```

Not working

```
func myFunc(data []int) {
    data = append(data, 1)
    fmt.Println(data)
}

func main() {
    d := []int { }
    myFunc(d)
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

With the introduction of the parameters as a pointer the original data can be modified

```
func myFuncNew(data *[]int) {
        *data = append(*data, 1)
    fmt.Println(*data)
}
```

Comment: Just tried out your advice re the templates, and I can confirm that it is not that, it is somewhere in the ClassRepository, I am almost 100% sure it has to do with a pointer I have been battling with them the whole day

Comment: Updated my question, I found the exact spot, I just don't know why

Comment: Sounds like the behavior of a slice where if you want the modified values you have to `slice := append(slice, newValue)`.  I think the populateClassRelationships has a copy of the classes slice so is not modifying the origional.

Comment: I learnt today though, that there is no such thing as a copy of a slice http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices

Comment: But that page also says "We must return the slice afterwards because, although Append can modify the elements of slice, the slice itself (the run-time data structure holding the pointer, length, and capacity) is passed by value."

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours on this damn problem

Comment: Working code https://play.golang.org/p/Nz8G3-jAJzI. Great example +1.